# Where does the current Bitcoin Core currently fail static analysis, if at all?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, compiling

I am looking into static analysis, and I'd like to know what to expect in the case of Bitcoin's main implementation, Bitcoin-Core.

That way, if I try static analysis on [Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin), I will know whether I've done it properly (e.g. I get something other than "Yay, everything's fine!" or "Boo, all is broken!").

There doesn't seem to be much out there beyond `make check` and [some Github issues](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20%22static%20analysis%22).

It could maybe stand some more independent research, but I want to check whether *somebody* out there knows this *already* (and is willing to subject themselves to the vagaries of the stackexchange communities enough to answer it).

**What are the current known static analysis issues with Bitcoin core, if any?**

Comment: Please feel free to post a comment if I'm not making this clear enough? Also note that I'm not talking about static analysis of Bitcoin opcodes like those discussed here: http://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2012-January/001024.html

Comment: Mentioning script somewhere in your question probably would have helped somewhat. The scripting language is somewhat dwarfed by the rest of the repository.

Comment: Static analysis is a very broad field.  Can you give some hints as to what kind of analysis you have in mind?

Comment: Mostly just the cryptography, actually.

Comment: Are there really that many failures, at the moment, for the current client? I'm not asking about the _field_ of static analysis.